# Why does including a header-only file in another header file included somewhere else cause redefinition?

Tags: linker, linker-errors

I have a header-only library, lets call it  `foo.h`, which is included into a `bar.h`, which is furthermore included into a `foobar.h`. The linker throws a LNK2005 error saying that the functions and structs from `foo.h` are already defined inside the `foobar.obj`.

The `foo.h` file looks something like this:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef  FOO 
#define FOO

//few structs and functions declarations and definitions (these aren't static nor inline) inside a namespace
#endif
//include guards added after I got the error for the first time
```

The `bar.h` looks like this:

```
#include "foo.h"
//some other code
```

The `foobar.h` looks like this:

```
#include "bar.h"
//some other code
```

This question is probably duplicit of this: [Why aren't include guards or pragma once working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787822/why-arent-include-guards-or-pragma-once-working)

But, is there another way to fix this than making these functions inline or static? Maybe without editing the `foo.h` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `bar.h` or `foobar.h` are included in several files.

The best solution to this is to declare all functions/methods in your file as `inline`. You could also declare them `static` (or, in case of C++, put them into anonymous namespace) but that's less efficient because code will be duplicated.